# Need to find prime and perfect integers from min max values in an input file

Tags: java

This is a homework question.

The code compiles, but in the test case, 2 is outputting as perfect, which it is not.

I cannot use an array. I cannot use `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`. Purely conditionals and loops.

My professor says I need to only test for divisors up to and including n/2 but when I do that, I still get the 2 as a perfect number.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Project2.java

import java.io.*; // BufferedReader
import java.util.*; // Scanner

public class Project2
{
  public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    // ALWAYS TEST FIRST TO VERIFY USER PUT REQUIRED CMD ARGS
    if (args.length < 3)
    {
      System.out.println("\nusage: C:\\> java Project2 <input file name> <lo>  <hi>\n\n");
      // i.e. C:\> java Project2 P2input.txt 1 30
      System.exit(0);
    }
    String infileName = args[0]; // i.e. L2input.txt
    int lo = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );   // i.e. 1
    int hi = Integer.parseInt( args[2] );   // i.e. 30

    // STEP #1: OPEN THE INPUT FILE AND COMPUTE THE MIN AND MAX. NO OUTPUT STATMENTS ALLOWED
    Scanner infile = new Scanner( new File(infileName) );
    int min,max;
    min=max=infile.nextInt(); // WE ASSUME INPUT FILE HAS AT LEAST ONE VALUE
    while ( infile.hasNextInt() )
    {
      // YOUR CODE HERE FIND THE MIN AND MAX VALUES OF THE FILE
      // USING THE LEAST POSSIBLE NUMBER OF COMPARISONS
      // ASSIGN CORRECT VALUES INTO min & max INTHIS LOOP.
      // MY CODE BELOW WILL FORMAT THEM TO THE SCREEN
      // DO NOT WRITE ANY OUTPUT TO THE SCREEN

      int number = infile.nextInt();

      if ( number < min )
      {
        min = number;
      }
      else if ( number > max )
      {
        max = number;
      }
    }



    System.out.format("min: %d max: %d\n",min,max); // DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY IN ANY WAY


    // STEP #2: DO NOT MODIFY THIS BLOCK
    // TEST EVERY NUMBER BETWEEN LO AND HI INCLUSIVE FOR
    // BEING PRIME AND/OR BEING PERFECT
    for ( int i=lo ; i<=hi ; ++i)
    {
      System.out.print( i );
      if ( isPrime(i) ) System.out.print( " prime ");
      if ( isPerfect(i) ) System.out.print( " perfect ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  } // END MAIN

  // *************** YOU FILL IN THE METHODS BELOW **********************

  // RETURNs true if and only if the number passed in is perfect
  static boolean isPerfect( int n )
  {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n/2; i ++)
    {
      if(n%i == 0)
      {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    if (sum == n)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
    // (just to make it compile) YOU CHANGE AS NEEDED
  }
  // RETURNs true if and only if the number passed in is prime
  static boolean isPrime( int n )
  {
    if (n < 3)
    {
      return false;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++)
    {
      if(n%i == 0)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;

  }// (just to make it compile) YOU CHANGE AS NEEDED
}
```

Comment: If I run your `isPerfect` method with 2 it returns false

Comment: Looking at your code it should return `false`

Comment: Weird. My professor uses a grading script.

Comment: It's kind of weird that you care enough to ask the question, but not enough to run your code yourself to verify that it's actually wrong.  Anyway, I'm not sure what else to do but vote to close the question, since your method works correctly and there's nothing for us to do.

Comment: I should clarify: I upload this to our intranet, where our professor runs a grading script. The output in that script as 2 as a prime as his answer, but mine is incorrect, or perfect.

Comment: @DM I _have_ run this code myself. I upload it to the intranet. I compile it, it works. The output in his grading script says that 2 is perfect. I am not sure what else you want.

Comment: I can't fix his grading script!  But I did find something wrong with a different method, and posted it as an answer.  Maybe his script just flagged the wrong thing wrong with 2.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a bug, although it's not quite the bug you described.

```
static boolean isPrime( int n )
{
    if (n < 3)
    {
      return false;
    }
```

This will incorrectly list 2 as not prime, because it's less than 3.